# Dynamic Extension creation in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip

I am looking for a way to configure asterisk to allow for dynamic creation of  extensions whenever a register command is received.   **Put security aside for the moment as this is for a development environment.**

Basically I have an unknown number of audio devices that I need to automatically create extensions for as I find these audio devices on my network.

I don't seem to see a way to do this.  All documentation seems to point to creating the extensions in configuration where the devices are all known up front.

Comment: I love how this community down votes without any comments whatsoever.  Gives me a warm fuzzy feeling and really makes me want to come back.  Remind me not to play D&D with you, I'm sure its about as fun as herpes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

> autocreatepeer = yes|no : If set, anyone will be able to log in as a
>   peer (with no check of credentials; useful for operation with SER).
>   Default no.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+sip.conf

Comment: this was exactly what was needed.